# How to read binary files until EOF in C#

Tags: c#, readfile, eof

I have a function to write some data into a binary file

```
private void writeToBinFile (List<MyClass> myObjList, string filePath)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

    foreach (MyClass myObj in myObjList)
    {
        bw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj));
    }
    bw.Close();
    fs.Close();

}
```

I am looking something like

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
BinaryReader bw = new BinaryReader(fs);

while (!filePath.EOF)
{
    List<MyClass> myObjList = br.Read(myFile);
}
```

anyone can help with this?
thanks in advance

Comment: `bw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj));` umm, pardon the stupid question. why did you use binary write to dump the json string..? is not its best to do something `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObjList)` then read them back as string and pass the string to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(myString)`?

Comment: I imagine you've used `BinaryWriter` to write your JSON so that you have individual records. A better way (if you want JSON) is to have one JSON object per line of the file, and then you could just use a regular `StreamReader`. Let me know if you want me to add an answer like this.

Comment: Hi, im new to C# i have tried bw.Write(myObj); but i have error saying cannot convert myObj to bool

Comment: @noobDev OK, but a binary file isn't usually human-readable. JSON is human-readable, so it seems a bit weird to mix binary and JSON.

Comment: yes @John thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON can be saved with no formatting (no new lines), so you can save 1 record per row of a file. Thus, my suggested solution is to ignore binary files and instead use a regular StreamWriter:

```
private void WriteToFile(List<MyClass> myObjList, string filePath)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filePath))
    {
        foreach (MyClass myObj in myObjList)
        {
            sw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));
        }
    }
}

private List<MyClass> ReadFromFile(string filePath)
{
    List<MyClass> myObjList = new List<MyClass>();
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        string line = null;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            myObjList.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(line));
        }
    }
    return myObjList;
}
```

If you really want to use the binary writer to save JSON, you could change it to be like this:

```
private void WriteToBinFile(List<MyClass> myObjList, string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
        foreach (MyClass myObj in myObjList)
        {
            bw.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj));
        }
    }
}

private List<MyClass> ReadFromBinFile(string filePath)
{
    List<MyClass> myObjList = new List<MyClass>();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileAccess.Read))
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {
        while (fs.Length != fs.Position) // This will throw an exception for non-seekable streams (stream.CanSeek == false), but filestreams are seekable so it's OK here
        {
            myObjList.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(br.ReadString()));
        }
    }
    return myObjList;
}
```

Notes:

- I've added [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) around your stream instantiations so that the files are properly closed when memory is freed
- To check the stream is at the end, you have to compare `Length` to `Position`.